# Phonegap Contacts API - Android - return only phone contacts and not gmail contacts

Tags: android, cordova, contacts

I am using phonegap 2.9.0 to retrieve the contacts list on android and iOS.

As you can see on the screenshot below, I got 67 contacts on the phone + 952 gmail contacts

[image: contacts]

The following code returns 1019 contacts. How is it possible to retrieve only the real contacts with the phonegap API?

Is there a group notion in phonegap? I read the documentation but the filter is pretty basic.

```
    var options      = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.multiple = true;
    var fields       = ["name", "phoneNumbers"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, function(contacts) { 
        for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
            console.log("Display Name = " + contacts[i].name.formatted);
            if(contacts[i].phoneNumbers)
              console.log("phone = " + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value);
        }
    }, function(contact_error) { 
      $scope.contact_has_error = true;  
    }, options);
```

thanks for your help

Comment: You could posssible get the email field too and can ignore if the email field is present. This is pure assumption that phone contacts don't have emails attached to it.

Comment: No I can't do that, all my phone contacts have an email and a phone number.
And btw, It would be nice to avoid to parse on my side ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, I wrote a plugin to return only the contacts with at least one phone numbers. The performances are way better.

https://github.com/dbaq/cordova-plugin-contacts-phone-numbers

Comment: That looks a good solution. But I don't know why is returning fail function all the time, on my nexus 4.

Comment: Open an issue on the repository, I might be able to help you: https://github.com/dbaq/cordova-plugin-contacts-phone-numbers/issues

Comment: This plug-in saved my life.